# Reading an array of dictionaries from plist

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray, plist, nsdictionary

Hi I'm trying to read in the values from a plist this is what my plist looks like atm

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Mickey Mouse</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>mickeymouse.png</string>
        <key>Hint1</key>
        <string>Hint 1</string>
        <key>Hint2</key>
        <string>Hint 2</string>
        <key>Hint3</key>
        <string>Hint 3</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Peter Pan</string>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>peterpan.png</string>
        <key>Hint1</key>
        <string>Hint 1</string>
        <key>Hint2</key>
        <string>Hint 2</string>
        <key>Hint3</key>
        <string>Hint 3</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

and this the code I'm using however It just crashes.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *questionNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Item 0"];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Level1" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *questionNumberDictionary = [array objectForKey:questionNumber];
NSString *questionTitle = [questionNumberDictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
NSString *questionImage = [questionNumberDictionary objectForKey:@"Image"];
NSString *questionHint1 = [questionNumberDictionary objectForKey:@"Hint1"];
NSString *questionHint2 = [questionNumberDictionary objectForKey:@"Hint2"];
NSString *questionHint3 = [questionNumberDictionary objectForKey:@"Hint3"];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a Problem at the following line

**`NSDictionary *questionNumberDictionary = [array objectForKey:questionNumber];`**

Instead of the you need to iterate over the Array using for loop

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Level1" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        NSString *questionTitle = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
        NSString *questionImage = [dict objectForKey:@"Image"];
        NSString *questionHint1 = [dict objectForKey:@"Hint1"];
        NSString *questionHint2 = [dict objectForKey:@"Hint2"];
        NSString *questionHint3 = [dict objectForKey:@"Hint3"];

    }
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually I'm still stuck how can I choose which Item in the array to use, currently when I use NSLog it shows me the values from the second item.

Comment: @Sami Can you clarify what you want to do ?. As if you will put NSLog(@"questionTitle == %@", questionTitle) statement in side for loop it will print vales for all the questionTitle in the array.